# XSLT to show a unique object name

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

**My XML input:**

```
<result>
    <objects name="wf1">
        <object>
            <qname>wf</qname>
            <object_name>Nr 1</object_name>
            <person_name>Anton</person_name>
        </object>
        <object>
            <qname>wf</qname>
            <object_name>Nr 2</object_name>
            <person_name>Ben</person_name>
        </object>
    </objects>
    
    <objects name="wf2">
        <object>
            <qname>wf</qname>
            <object_name>Nr 2</object_name>
            <person_name>Chris</person_name>
        </object>
        <object>
            <qname>wf</qname>
            <object_name>Nr 3</object_name>
            <person_name>Dirk</person_name>
        </object>
    </objects>
</result>
```

Things to note

- There are two blocks with information: wf1 and wf2
- Both have an object with object_name = 'Nr 2'
- All objects have qname = 'wf'

**My XSLT:**

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:call-template name="output_html" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="output_html">
    <html>
        <body >
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Object name</th>
                    <th>Person name</th>
                </tr>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="result/objects/object[qname='wf']" />
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="object[*]"> 
    <tr align="center" valign="top">
        <td><xsl:value-of select="object_name"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="person_name"/></td>
    </tr>   
</xsl:template>
```

**Output:**

| Object name | Person name |
| --- | --- |
| Nr 1 | Anton |
| Nr 2 | Ben |
| Nr 2 | Chris |
| Nr 3 | Dirk |

**My wish:**

I would like to see unique object names. If an object with a certain name appears in both wf1 and wf2 then only the one from wf2 should be shown.
So the desired output would be:

| Object name | Person name |
| --- | --- |
| Nr 1 | Anton |
| Nr 2 | Chris |
| Nr 3 | Dirk |

The information "Ben" gets lost. That is fine.

Does anybody have ideas about how to achieve that in XSLT 1.0?

Comment: Use a key or group the elements to output only the first item of each group.

Comment: In all your questions regarding XSLT, please state which version of XSLT your processor supports. This is especially important here with what is essentially a [grouping](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt-grouping/info) question.

Comment: Thank you Michael. I have added that I'm looking for a 1.0 solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XSLT 1.0, it would be best to adapt the [Muenchian method](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) to the current problem:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="obj-by-name" match="object" use="object_name" />

<xsl:template match="/result">
    <html>
        <body >
            <table>
                <!-- header -->
                <tr>
                    <th>Object name</th>
                    <th>Person name</th>
                </tr>
                <!-- for each distinct object_name -->
                <xsl:for-each select="objects/object[count(. | key('obj-by-name', object_name)[1]) = 1]">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="object_name"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <!-- sort the group with wf2 on top -->
                            <xsl:for-each select="key('obj-by-name', object_name)">
                                <xsl:sort select="number(../@name='wf2')" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
                                <xsl:if test="position()=1">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="person_name"/>
                                </xsl:if>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </td>
                    </tr> 
                </xsl:for-each>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

If `<objects name="wf2">` will always come **after**  `<objects name="wf1">`, then you can shorten this to:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="obj-by-name" match="object" use="object_name" />

<xsl:template match="/result">
    <html>
        <body >
            <table>
                <!-- header -->
                <tr>
                    <th>Object name</th>
                    <th>Person name</th>
                </tr>
                <!-- for each distinct object_name -->
                <xsl:for-each select="objects/object[count(. | key('obj-by-name', object_name)[1]) = 1]">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="object_name"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="key('obj-by-name', object_name)[last()]/person_name"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr> 
                </xsl:for-each>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```